# Trigger specific environment from specific artifact trigger

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have the following-ish setup in vsts release.

[image]

What I would like, is whenever the "hotfix" artifact build is triggered, the bottom pipeline ("Environment 1", "Environment 2") are triggered, whilst if the top one "master" is triggered the top 3 are.

How can I go about it?

I realise I could do them in seperate releases, but I already have a lot of them and grouping related ones this way should hopefully make it easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, the workaround is separate the environments into different release definition based on artifacts.

And if you need to trigger different environments based on different artifacts, you can create an [user voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services).